# Recover from resetting commit without pushing

Tags: git, commit, reset, recover

I had two commits yesterday and couldn't push because I didn't have an internet connection. After that, I wrote some code and realized it's pretty messy and wanted to revert it to a HEAD commit. I did `git reset --hard HEAD` and some of my files (I'm pretty sure I commited) were lost. Now I'm looking at a week old version and my git status says `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits`. Some of the 'lost' files are listed in my git status as modified even though they are empty files on my system (just the include header).

Is my code recoverable?

Answer (score 0):

If you really made commits you can see the revision history with `git reflog`. It lists all actions done on your clone independently of branches and tags.

However if you did `git reset --hard HEAD` on a repo with local changes (staged or not) they are lost - this seems to be your case. When running `git log` do you still see the 2 commits you made yesterday in the log? This is indicated by the message *Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits*.

Comment: Yes, I see the two commits.

Comment: Do the two commits contain the changes you fear to have lost?

Comment: Yes. I just realized, in xCode when comparing versions, i can see my Local(current) version and the HEAD version which is indeed the code that is lost. The problem is that some files are missing and I kind of need em aswell.

Comment: Maybe your environment (XCode) is running `git clean` as well, then even unknown-to-git-files are deleted.